# JGraph in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jgrapht

I want to draw some graphs including vertices and edges in my application. I found that JGraph is a good library for plotting graphs. I went through some online sources about it but couldn't find any relevant articles about how to embed a JGraph in a Swing application.  (Showing a JGraph in a `JFrame` etc).  Can Any one help me with that?

Comment: See [JGraph support](http://www.jgraph.com/support.html).

Comment: Do you want help actually drawing a graph or getting it to appear in the JFrame? Do you want to know how to take data and have it appear on the graph?

Comment: or http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/CatalogChart.htm, but tutorials and forums are on authors sited by defalut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
// Insert the cells via the cache, so they get selected
graph.getGraphLayoutCache().insert(cells);

// Show in Frame
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(graph));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you want the whole sample i can upload it too.

I think the code must be a modified sample from the site. Here you go:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import org.jgraph.JGraph;
import org.jgraph.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgraph.graph.DefaultGraphCell;
import org.jgraph.graph.DefaultGraphModel;
import org.jgraph.graph.GraphConstants;
import org.jgraph.graph.GraphModel;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Construct Model and Graph
        GraphModel model = new DefaultGraphModel();
        JGraph graph = new JGraph(model);
        // Control-drag should clone selection
        graph.setCloneable(true);

        // Enable edit without final RETURN keystroke
        graph.setInvokesStopCellEditing(true);

        // When over a cell, jump to its default port (we only have one, anyway)
        graph.setJumpToDefaultPort(true);

        // Insert all three cells in one call, so we need an array to store them
        DefaultGraphCell[] cells = new DefaultGraphCell[3];

        // Create Hello Vertex
        cells[0] = createVertex("Hello", 20, 20, 40, 20, null, false );

        // Create World Vertex
        cells[1] = createVertex("World", 140, 140, 40, 20,
                Color.ORANGE, true);

        // Create Edge
        DefaultEdge edge = new DefaultEdge("foo");
        // Fetch the ports from the new vertices, and connect them with the edge
        edge.setSource(cells[0].getChildAt(0));
        edge.setTarget(cells[0].getChildAt(0));
        cells[2] = edge;

        // Create Edge
        DefaultEdge edge1 = new DefaultEdge();
        // Fetch the ports from the new vertices, and connect them with the edge
//        cells[0].addPort();
//        cells[1].addPort();
//        edge1.setSource(cells[1]);
//        edge1.setTarget(cells[0]);
//        cells[3] = edge1;

        // Set Arrow Style for edge
        int arrow = GraphConstants.ARROW_CLASSIC;
        GraphConstants.setLineEnd(edge.getAttributes(), arrow);
        GraphConstants.setEndFill(edge.getAttributes(), true);

        // Insert the cells via the cache, so they get selected
        graph.getGraphLayoutCache().insert(cells);

        // Show in Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(graph));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static DefaultGraphCell createVertex(String name, double x,
            double y, double w, double h, Color bg, boolean raised) {

        // Create vertex with the given name
        DefaultGraphCell cell = new DefaultGraphCell(name);

        // Set bounds
        GraphConstants.setBounds(cell.getAttributes(),
                new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, w, h));

        // Set fill color
        if (bg != null) {
            GraphConstants.setGradientColor(cell.getAttributes(), bg);
            GraphConstants.setOpaque(cell.getAttributes(), true);
        }

        // Set raised border
        if (raised) {
            GraphConstants.setBorder(cell.getAttributes(),
                    BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
        } else // Set black border
        {
            GraphConstants.setBorderColor(cell.getAttributes(),
                    Color.black);
        }
        // Add a Floating Port
        cell.addPort();

        return cell;
    }
}
```

This is a very simple example. I have done a few complicated graphs of database data, but ended up working with [Jung2](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/) which fits my needs better.

Comment: can u please upload the whole sample.. That will be very helpful to me!!!! thanxx

Answer (score 2):

`JGraph` includes the packages `com.mxgraph.examples.swing` and `com.mxgraph.examples.swing.editor` in the examples folder:

```
$ ls examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing
ClickHandler.java   GraphEditor.java    SchemaEditor.java   editor
CustomCanvas.java   HelloWorld.java     UserObject.java     images
FixedPoints.java    Port.java       Validation.java     resources

$ ls examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/editor
BasicGraphEditor.java       EditorMenuBar.java      JTableRenderer.java
DefaultFileFilter.java      EditorPalette.java      SchemaEditorMenuBar.java
EditorAboutFrame.java       EditorPopupMenu.java        SchemaEditorToolBar.java
EditorActions.java      EditorRuler.java        SchemaGraphComponent.java
EditorKeyboardHandler.java  EditorToolBar.java      ShadowBorder.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is [G](http://geosoft.no/graphics/).