# JGraph create uni/bidirectional graph of paths

Tags: java, graph, jgraph

I'm working on visualization of shortest path algorithms. I have a graph of edges and vertices and I'd like to draw it using JGraph. So far I used as an example this code: [JGraph in a JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722035/jgraph-in-a-jframe/6722760#6722760?newreg=ba45ffb76a83421c8042cb21e9085a3c)

It works nice, but it has fixed coordinates of cells(vertices). I plan to have a LinkedList of randomly generated number of vertices and edges of random length, and some edges will be uni or bidirectional.

How to create such JGraph that will automatically place cells in suitable way? Coordinates are arbitrary but lengths have to maintain proportions. Do I need to use external algorithm to do that?

Comment: I have a similar problem, did you use an external algorithm in the end? thanks :)

Comment: Sadly no, I gave up and left just console representation witch points will it 'visit'.